# Spring RestController returning ResponseEntity<byte[]> in case of errors

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a rest controller in a spring boot service as follows:

Public ResponseEntity getDocContent(String id)

THis controller action produces MediaType.Octet_Stream

I am wondering what to return in case of non Http OK response when I really don’t have a byte array content but a String with error message. I would not want to produce an octet stream in error cases but an error JSon instead

I can have The service produce both octet stream and application/json but my confusion is around the return type of byte array in case of errors in which case I want to generate a Json and not a byte array

Please give me ideas on how to solve this

Comment: did you try throwing an exception and handling it on the front end?

Comment: I still need to return an error HttpStatus code in case of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `controllerAdvice` to handle the thrown exceptions in the `RestContoller`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{


    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT) //Just an example code
    public ResponseEntity<GeneralMessage> handleGacaException(MyException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
        GeneralMessage errorMessage = new GeneralMessage(ex.getErrorCode().toString(), ex.getErrorMessage());

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(errorMessage);
    }


}
```

Than throw `MyException` on the RestController.